# Django-CMS text editing not working on Apache

Tags: django, apache, mod-wsgi, django-cms

When serving my django-cms application on apache with mod_wsgi I can't get the text-plugin to work.

The difference is that when serving on apache the textedito tries to get an url that does not exist.
On Apache:
/admin/js/iframe/default/wymiframe.html

With manage.py runserver
/static/cms/wymeditor/iframe/default/wymiframe.html

the wymiframe.html file is present in my static folder and is accessible but not via the wrong URL that I get when running the app through apache.

What do I do to get the text-plugin requesting the right URL?

Answer (score 0):

What have you set STATIC_URL to in your settings file? That in part is what controls paths when links are created.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/howto/deployment/wsgi/modwsgi/#serving-the-admin-files

Comment: My problem was that I have static content on a subdomain and did not setb Access-Control-Allow-Origin since django-cms uses a mix of iframes generaded with the admin interface and some content from the static folder. Thanks anyways!

Answer (score 0):

My problem was that I served static content on a subdomain and I had problems with Access Control.

My solution was to set

```
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin *
```

in my apache config file